# android studio se cierra al analizar el proyecto

Tags: java, android-studio

verán, cuando inicio el programa y creo nuevos proyectos el android studio se cierra solo, he notado que es cuando aparece el mensaje de indexing o analizing del proyecto.

- he reinstalado el programa
- instale el driver para amd
- cree otro proyecto con otras versión

encontré esto en el archivo idea.log

```
2021-08-07 17:32:21,687 [   6238]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922 
2021-08-07 17:32:21,703 [   6254]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2021-08-07 17:32:21,703 [   6254]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - OS: Windows 10
```

y aun así se sigue cerrando, tampoco se muestra algún mensaje de error o algún indicio ¿Qué puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable que instales "Android Studio Arctic Fox", aunque hasta el día de hoy Agosto 2021 se encuentra en un canal estable tiene aún problemas, ve a `File` > `Invalidates Cache/Restart` probablemente sea algo relacionado al realizar la actualización de tu IDE.

Para tener mas información del error ve a

`Help` > `Show Log in Explorer`

---

Lo recomentable es instalar la version actual desde :

https://developer.android.com/studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola @jorgesys agradezco su amable ayuda, vera esa fue la versión que instale, precisamente de esa web, nose que pudo haber ocurrido, por otro lado ya hice lo que me comento y sigue igual :/

Comment: Si actualizaste te sugiero realizar File > Invalidates Cache/Restart. Revisaste que se muestra en el Log de Android Studio ?